# How to test useEffect call of child component using jest and react-native testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, use-effect, react-testing-library

I use react-native and react-native testing library with jest. The component structure is as follows.

```js
function doSomething(x) {
    return x.map(i => i)
}

const ComponentA = (props) => {

    const data = React.useMemo(() => {
       return doSomething(props.data)
    }, [props.data])

    return <ComponentB data={data} />
}

const ComponentB = (props) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // do something
    }, [props.data])

   return (...)
}
```

I want to test that the `useEffect` in `ComponentB` is called only once if `props.data` passed to `ComponentA` does not change. The use of `useMemo` fixed a bug which caused the `useEffect` in `ComponentB` to be called on every render of `ComponentA` since `map` returns a new array on each call. Thus, without making it stable, the `useEffect` will be  called on every render.

I am unsure how to test the call of `useEffect` in `ComponentB` on render of `ComponentA`.

Here is what I have so far.

```js
describe("Test component", () => {
  const useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect")

  it("test component b useEffect", () => {
    const  data = []
    const component = <ComponentA data={data} />
    const { rerender } = render(component)

    expect(useEffect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    void act(() => {
      rerender(component)
    })

    // data props has not changed
    expect(useEffect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    ...
  })
})
```

This is obviously wrong and incomplete. How do I correctly check the calls of `useEffect` in `ComponentB`?

Comment: I think the most robust way would be to pull the `// do something` of the `useEffect` into another file and mock that, and check that's only been called once. Then you're not messing around tying it to `useEffect` (say you add an unrelated `useEffect` in the future)